# Scapy throwing syntax error for python 2.6.6 application

Tags: python, syntax-error, scapy

I had worked on a program in Python2.7 and need to retool it for Python 2.6.6. I made some minor changes but receive this error when trying to compile. Has anyone ran into this before? I couldn't find very much on Google. Any help would be appreciated

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makexml.py", line 13, in <module>
    from scapy.all import rdpcap
  File "/user/.pyenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site- 
  packages/scapy/all.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scapy.config import *
  File "/user/.pyenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site- 
packages/scapy/config.py", line 84
    self.layers = {owner for f in self.fields for owner in f.owners}
                           ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Set comprehensions are a new feature from Python 3 that [got backported to Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features).

So if you try to use one in an earlier version, you get a `SyntaxError`.

The simplest change is to pass a generator expression to the `set` constructor:

```
self.layers = set(owner for f in self.fields for owner in f.owners)
```

(This will work all the way back to 2.4. Before that, there's no builtin `set`, and no generator expressions, but you'd probably have bigger problems with, e.g., exceptions…)

Answer (score 0):

Scapy 2.4.0 is not compatible with Python 2.6. You should downgrade Scapy to 2.3.3, which has Python 2.6 (and 2.5, I think) support.